# Search for multiple id:s in cloudant

Tags: database, nosql, cloudant, node-red

I am using node-red to communicate with cloudant and for each time my flow runs I might have different amount of id:s coming in msg.payload. Later I want to use these id:s to display all the relevant objects. Is it possible to search for multiple id:s in some way? Or do you have any other solution? Can't find anything about this online atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Node-RED supports querying by _id, a search index, or all documents. When you use _id there does not seem to be a way to specify more than one ID. You can use a search index, however, to query for multiple IDs.

Create a search index in Cloudant similar to the following:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/allDocSearch",
  "views": {},
  "language": "javascript",
  "indexes": {
    "byId": {
      "analyzer": "standard",
      "index": "function (doc) {\n  index(\"id\", doc._id);\n}"
    }
  }
}
```

This corresponds to the following when using the Cloudant dashboard:

design doc = `allDocSearch`

index name = `byId`

index function =

```
function (doc) {
  index("name", doc.name);
}
```

To search for multiple IDs your query would look something like this:

```
id:"1" OR id:"2"
```

In Node-Red set up your Cloudant node to point to the appropriate database, specify a "Search by" of `search index`, and configure your design document and index name (in this case it would be `allDocSearch/byId`).

You can test with a simple inject node with a payload similar to the search query above: `id:"1" OR id:"2"`

Comment: Thanks! That's a great solution. I also managed to solve the problem by splitting the objects so it loops and searches for one id at the time